# Been trying to install mongoDB using brew, all my attempts fail and error. I'm using macOS big sur with Xcode 12 beta installed

Tags: mongodb, homebrew, macos-big-sur

An exception occurred within a child process:
NoMethodError: undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  paths

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?  I am facing the same issue.